# (Python 2.7) Access variable from class with accessor/mutator

Tags: python, class, typeerror, accessor

(Python 2.7) I'm trying to access the vertices variable from the SierpinskiTriangle class and use it in the second bit of code listed but it shows

> TypeError: 'property' object is not iterable

I can only assume it is due to the accessors/mutators

**Base code:**

```
class Fractal(object):

# the constructor
def __init__(self, dimensions):
    # the canvas dimensions
    self.dimensions = dimensions
    # the default number of points to plot is 50,000
    self.num_points = 50000
    # the default distance ratio is 0.5 (halfway)
    self.r = 0.5

# accessors and mutators
@property
def vertices(self):
    return self._vertices

@vertices.setter
def vertices(self, v):
    self._vertices = v


class SierpinskiTriangle(Fractal):
# the constructor
def __init__(self, canvas):
    # call the constructor in the superclass
    Fractal.__init__(self, canvas)
    # define the vertices based on the fractal size
    v1 = Point(self.dimensions["mid_x"], self.dimensions["min_y"])
    v2 = Point(self.dimensions["min_x"], self.dimensions["max_y"])
    v3 = Point(self.dimensions["max_x"], self.dimensions["max_y"])
    self.vertices = [ v1, v2, v3 ]
```

**Code to get vertices in:**

```
class ChaosGame(Canvas):

vertex_radius = 2
vertex_color = "red"
point_radius = 0
point_color = "black"

def __init__(self, master):
    Canvas.__init__(self, master, bg = "white")
    self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

# a function that takes a string that represents the fractal to create
def make(self, f):
    if f == "SierpinskiTriangle":
        vertices = SierpinskiTriangle.vertices
    if f == "SierpinskiCarpet":
        vertices = []
    if f == "Pentagon":
        vertices = []
    if f == "Hexagon":
        vertices = []
    if f == "Octagon":
        vertices = []

    print vertices
    for point in vertices:
        self.plot_point(self, point, ChaosGame.vertex_color, ChaosGame.vertex_radius)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are accessing the class instead of an object of that type.

Let's try it on a minimal example:

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self):
        self._content = range(10)

    @property
    def content(self):
        return self._content

    @content.setter
    def set_content(self, c):
        self._content = c
```

This works:

```
c = Container()
for number in c.content:
    print(number)
```

(prints out numbers from 0 to 9).

But this fails:

```
for number in Container.content:
    print(number)
```

with the error

```
TypeError        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-f1df89781355> in <module>()
      1 # This doesn't:
----> 2 for number in Container.content:
      3     print(number)

TypeError: 'property' object is not iterable
```

Besides of the problems with the properties, you didn't initialize an object, so the `__init__` function of the class was never called and `Container._content` was not initialized.

In fact, you would get a similar problem if you had just used

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = range(10)
```

(only that it would be an attribute error in this case).
Final note: This

```
for number in Container().content:  # note the '()'!!
    print(number)
```

works again, because we create a container object on the fly.